# Using home grown Model system with CI_Model in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

Has anyone used two different MVC systems together -- like ZF and CI or Symfony and CI, etc?

I have two parts of a web site, the front-end that was written in an MVC system I built myself and that works well (and is very similar to CodeIgniter). The back-end will be written in CI because I am working with two other people and my system isn't as documented and tested as CI. We are not planning to rewrite the front-end at this time.

I have models defined, extending an existing class that has all the db stuff, some ease-of-use functions, etc. Normal model stuff. Is there a way I can use these same models with my system and also with CI_Model without having to rewrite my existing system but also not have to store (and maintain) a copy of each model?

I was thinking about changing my models to extend CI_Model instead but then I have to use all the other under-the-hood stuff in CI and I'm not ready to do that.

Thanks

Comment: I do the opposite, i use CI's view system and Doctrine for the models. :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up, after finding no way to have them co-exist easily, convert the entire thing, front-side and all, to CI. Done and done.